# How to login by using my own Controller?

Tags: spring-security

My app is a full RESTful style web application which provides JSON interfaces only(no web pages). I want to write my own controller that I can fully control the login process:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam String username,
                        @RequestParam String password,
                        HttpServletRequest req,
                        HttpServletResponse resp) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        try {
            Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(token);            
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }


        return "success";
```

And this is my `UserDetailsService`:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (!name.equals("whf")) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("not found");
        }


        // load roles
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"));

        return new User("whf", "pwd", authorities);
    }
}
```

But when I access the URL that requires `admin` role,  I got `Access is Denied`:

```
@GetMapping("/a")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
    public String A(Principal principal) {
        return "a";
    }
```

Current user has been given the `admin` role. Why can't I access `/a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.
I missed the `ROLE_` prefix at the step of granting authority.